# what are the options for client templates for asp.net application

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates

Now that jquery templates are discontinuing and jsrender and jsview are still in beta, what are the good options for rendering data retrieved by jquery ajax?

Comment: CSS maybe? I never found the use of clientside templates, as the serverside projects are much more mature.

Answer (score 1):

[KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) is incredible.

It supports a template system based on the older jQuery template syntax.

It also supports the MVVM pattern by allowing you to create a JavaScript ViewModel using the Knockout observables, and dependentObservable functions which can be two-way bound to dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

My favorites are [$.EJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.EJS) (because it compiles into crazy fast production JavaScript) and [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) (because language agnostic templates are awesome).